# Url scope encoding versus cgi.query_string encoding

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

Can someone explain the following result.

Request:

```
?q=argentini%C3%AB
```

Code on requested page:

```
<Cfoutput>cgi.query_string: #cgi.query_string#</Cfoutput>
<Cfoutput>url.q: #url.q#</Cfoutput>
```

Output on requested page:

```
cgi.query_string: argentinië
url.q: argentini?
```

For some reason url.q outputs to *argentini?* and not *argentinië*. I think this has something todo with the encoding of the different variables.

***Update***:

After further testing i figured out that the problem is in the Helicon ISAPI_Rewrite plugin for IIS, not coldfusion.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764446/problem-using-unicode-in-urls-with-cgi-path-info-in-coldfusion

Comment: What does `<cfdump var="#url#">` show? The above works for me in CF10, it displays the `ë` in both cases.